# Does the external hardware interrupt affect both cores in ESP32?

Tags: interrupts, esp32, freertos

I am working on a project, where I am implementing FreeRTOS on an ESP32 DEVKIT-V1 module. One core is specifically dedicated to reading high precision rotary encoders. I am reading the number of encoder ticks via Interrupts for six motors in total.

I am wondering, do the interrupts from these six motors affect only one core (if so - which?) or does it affect both? Is it possible to limit the interrupt to one core only?

Comment: Ah, both esp32 and Rpi Pico has two cores, and both can be programmed using microPython, with one core dedicated to interrupt handling.  There are couple of newbie friendly tutorials on the Internet, eg. Dual Cores & Interrupts on Pi Pico By tonygo2 in CircuitsMicrocontrollers8,75490Featured
https://www.instructables.com/Dual-Cores-Interrupts-on-Pi-Pico/